# show dates when using only HourInterval in RadTimeline wpf

Tags: wpf, telerik

[image]I am not much familiar with "Wpf" and "Telerik" Controls.

I am using

```
telerik RadTimeline
```

and want to show timeline in

```
HourInterval.
```

User can select start and end date and timeline will show interval in Hour basis.

But the problem with this timeline is that it is showing only the Hours but not the date in which this Hour exist.So, User can be confused.

It will be great if the Date can be shown in the topmost row of the timeline
You can check this code by scrolling in debugging mode.

```
<telerik:RadTimeline x:Name="timeline"
               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
               PeriodStart="1-Jan-2010 12:00:00 AM" PeriodEnd="3-Jan-2010 11:59:59 PM">
    <telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>                   
        <telerik:HourInterval />                   
    </telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>
</telerik:RadTimeline>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom IntervalFormatterProvider

```
<Window xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:formatter="clr-namespace:YouFormatterNamespace"
>
<telerik:RadTimeline x:Name="timeline"
           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
           PeriodStart="1-Jan-2010 12:00:00 AM" PeriodEnd="3-Jan-2010 11:59:59 PM">
    <telerik:RadTimeline.Resources>
            <formatter:HourFormatterProvider x:Key="HourFormatterProvider">
            </formatter:HourFormatterProvider>                
    </telerik:RadTimeline.Resources>
    <telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>
            <telerik:HourInterval FormatterProvider="{StaticResource HourFormatterProvider}"/>            
    </telerik:RadTimeline.Intervals>
</telerik:RadTimeline>
</Window>
```

Provider example:

```
public class HourFormatterProvider : IIntervalFormatterProvider
{
    private static readonly Func<DateTime, string>[] formatters;
    private Func<DateTime, string>[] intervalSpanFormatters;

    static HourFormatterProvider()
    {
        formatters = new Func<DateTime, string>[]
        {
            date => date.ToString("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        };
    }

    public Func<DateTime, string>[] GetFormatters(IntervalBase interval)
    {
        return formatters;
    }

    public Func<DateTime, string>[] GetIntervalSpanFormatters(IntervalBase interval)
    {
        if (this.intervalSpanFormatters == null)
        {
            this.intervalSpanFormatters = new Func<DateTime, string>[]
            {
                date => String.Format("{0} - {1}", date.ToString("dddd H:mm"), interval.IncrementByCurrentInterval(date).ToString("H:mm"))
            };
        }

        return this.intervalSpanFormatters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Error 1 The resource "HourFormatterProvider" could not be resolved in designer side

Comment: You need to add a reference to your formatter inside the xaml. I've edited my answer.

Comment: can i show dates separately in a row above where it is showing @LucaPerotti

Comment: I want to show the date instead of time 03 AM ,04 AM as shown in the figure.